# Installation procedure for phonegap 2.9.1

Tags: macos, cordova

How to install phonegap 2.9.1 without using terminal in my mac pc,which package i need to install from that folder?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there isn't a package for you to install phonegap without using the terminal right now.

Try [this link](http://tylermauthe.com/2013/11/09/phonegap-ios-osx-mavericks.html) to install it, if you haven't already.

Don't be afraid to use the terminal! It's your friend `:)`

Comment: I installed through terminal,but is there any way to get separate template for phone gap after installation (i.e single view application,Master-detail application)